# saving canvas image to local storage

Tags: c#, canvas

I'm making a windows phone app in Visual Studio 2013 with a canvas object and saving what I draw as a jpeg in local internal storage. The image being saved is black though. I've found plenty of threads dealing with this problem in Android but nothing for Windows Phone / C#. My current code is as follows:

```
public static void SaveImage(Canvas c, string filename)
    {
        var bmp = new WriteableBitmap(421, 627);
        bmp.Render(c, null);

        using (IsolatedStorageFile storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = storage.CreateFile(filename))
            {
                bmp.SaveJpeg(stream, 200, 100, 0, 95);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

There must be plenty of examples for saving bitmaps onto local storage. Any guidance is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to write like there:http://teusje.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/c-save-a-canvas-as-an-image/

Or there:
[http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2008/09/18/wpf-xaml-saving-a-window-or-canvas-as-a-png-bitmap.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2008/09/18/wpf-xaml-saving-a-window-or-canvas-as-a-png-bitmap.aspxhttp://blogs.msdn.com/b/saveenr/archive/2008/09/18/wpf-xaml-saving-a-window-or-canvas-as-a-png-bitmap.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the link but I've found what's missing from my code above. I just had to insert the line "bmp.Invalidate();" after bmp.Render.